# Should I put a "required" data annotation in Model or viewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not sure how to go about setting up my data model.

I'm using: **MVC 5, EF 6.1.3**

I have a Model class that has several properties(decorated with several "Required" data annotation attributes to reflect on the database table created), those fields are populated using a viewModel within my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateRequestViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Affiliations = _context.Affiliations.ToList();
        viewModel.Issues = _context.Issues.ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var request = new Request
    {
        RequestDate = DateTime.Today,
        Status = "Open",
        FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
        LastName = viewModel.LastName,
        AffiliationId = viewModel.Affiliation,
        IssueId = viewModel.Issue,
        LastModificationDate = DateTime.Now,
        RequestTypeId = 2,
    };

    _context.Requests.Add(request);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return View("Success");
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Request
{
    [Display(Name = "Request ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Request Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Modified")]
    public DateTime LastModificationDate { get; set; }

    //navigations properties
    public Affiliation Affiliation { get; set; }
    public Issue Issue { get; set; }
    public RequestType RequestType { get; set; }

    //foreign keys
    [Display(Name = "Affiliation")]
    public byte AffiliationId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Issue")]
    public int IssueId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Request Type")]
    public byte RequestTypeId { get; set; }


}
```

CreateRequestViewModel Class:

```
public class CreateRequestViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<Affiliation> Affiliations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Issue> Issues { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    public byte Affiliation { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    public int Issue { get; set; }
}
```

However, if I want to update some of the fields on the database table that reflects the Model class, I have to load all the required properties and then save them again because of the "required" data annotations. The issue is I just need to update a a few but but not all properties(for example: I wouldn't be changing FirstName or LastName values).

**My question**: Should I remove the "Required" data annotation attributes from my Model class and set those data annotations on viewModel for user input? If I do then I lose the "NOT NULL" constraints for the fields on my Database table, but it is enforced through my modelView. Or should I load the entire Model object and save all the properties again before calling .SaveChanges() on my dbcontext?

**Note**: I removed several extra properties in my model and viewModel to shorten the code here.

**EDIT**;
I ended up implementing the following code to avoid changing the model. It seems to work fine.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details(DetailsViewModel request)
    {

        var model = new Request
        {
            Id = request.Id,
            RequestDate = request.RequestDate,
            Status = request.Status,
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            LastModificationDate = DateTime.Now,
            AffiliationId = request.AffiliationId,
            IssueId = request.IssueId,
            RequestTypeId = request.RequestTypeId,

        };

        _context.Requests.Attach(model);
        var entry = _context.Entry(model);
        entry.Property(e => e.Status).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(e => e.AffiliationId).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(e => e.IssueId).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(e => e.RequestTypeId).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(e => e.LastModificationDate).IsModified = true;

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Requests");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If First Name (and other properties marked as required in Model) is a required field, then you should decorate your Model  (so that in table, that field will be marked as not null) as well as ViewModel (for ModelState validations and to show error message in ui in case you are using jQuery validator) with required attribute
2. For updating only few properties while update, you dont have to load the entire entity, instead you could mark state of specific property as Modified.

   var entry = context.Entry(your entity);
    entry.Property(e=> e.YourChangedProperty1).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(e=>      e.YourChangedProperty2).IsModified = true;
    context.SaveChanges();

Comment: So I ended up doing this instead:  It works but not sure if appropriate since I'm still bringing all properties passed over by a View.

  _context.Requests.Attach(model);
            var entry = _context.Entry(model);
            entry.Property(e => e.Status).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(e => e.AffiliationId).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(e => e.IssueId).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(e => e.RequestTypeId).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(e => e.LastModificationDate).IsModified = true;

            _context.SaveChanges();

Comment: @Joe Cuevas: if your Request entity is huge and you just gotta update few properties, this is how *I do*. But may be thats a personal choice. When I'm in doubt,  I usually verify the query generated in profiler/intellitrace to check whether the EF generated query is close to what we have in our mind.

Answer (score 1):

Put required in your datamodel where it makes sense. If the data entity always requires firstname, put it up there.

If your viewmodel doesnt require the firstname, dont put it there.
If you need your user input to contain a property, then put required on that property in your vm.

Loading your entity to update it is perfectly fine. Changing vm to "fix" some data entity is not.